# Convergence in distribution of sum of two random variables, simple case

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

$X_n, Y_n$ are random variables on the same probability space and it's known that $X_n \rightarrow X$ and $Y_n \rightarrow 0 =: Y$ in distribution. Proof that $X_n + Y_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution.

I have a problem because of the case, when $x\ge 0$ (then $F_Y$ = 1).

I need to proof that $|F_{X_n + Y_n} - F_Y| < \varepsilon$ for large n, I've tried to estimate
$F_{X_n + Y_n}(x) = P(X_n + Y_n \le x) \le P(X_n \le x) + P(Y_n \le 0)$, but it doesn't work, because $P(Y_n \le 0) = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $P(X_n+Y_n \leq z) \leq P(X_n+Y_n \leq z, |Y_n| <\epsilon)+P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon)$. Also $P(X_n+Y_n \leq z, |Y_n| <\epsilon) \leq P(X_n \leq z+\epsilon)$. Can you show using these that $\lim \sup P(X_n+Y_n \leq z) \leq P(X \leq z)$? A similar argument gives $\lim \inf P(X_n+Y_n \leq z) \geq P(X \leq z)$ provided $(X=z)=0$.

Comment: I'm going through the proof right now and I'm stuck at $\lim \sup P(X_n+Y_n \leq z) \leq \lim \sup P(X_n - \epsilon \leq z)+ \lim \sup P(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon)$. Of course, $\lim \sup P(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon)$ will go to zero but why is $ \lim \sup P(X_n - \epsilon \leq z) = P(X-\epsilon \leq z)$? And also, why does the inequality flip for the $\lim \inf$? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: @psyph $X_n \to X$ indistribution implies that $\lim \sup P(X_n \leq t) \leq P(X \leq t)$ for every real number $t$. Take $t=\epsilon +z$. For your second question use the fact that $X_n \leq z-\epsilon$ implies that either $|Y_n| >\epsilon$ or $X_n+Y_n \leq z$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. But I don't think I quite understand the second point. Maybe to clarify my question, based on the inequality $P(X_n + Y_n \leq z)\leq P(X_n-\epsilon \leq z)+P(|Y_n|> \epsilon)$, why do I take the $\lim \sup$ straight up but apparently not the $\lim \inf$.

Comment: @psyph Proving that $a_n \to a$ is equivalent to proving that $\lim \sup a_n \leq a$ and $\lim \inf a_n \geq a$.

Comment: Thanks, that I know already (since it is the goal of the proof), but what I wanted to know was, does $\lim \inf P(X_n +Y_n \leq z) \geq \lim \inf P(X_n-\epsilon \leq z)+ \lim \inf P(|Y_n|>\epsilon)$ hold, and if so, why? Sorry for asking imprecise questions on my part.

Comment: @psyph No that inequality does not hold.

Comment: Ok, so do I take $\lim \inf P(X_n+Y_n \leq z) \leq \lim \inf P(X_n -\epsilon \leq z) + \lim \inf P(|Y_n|>\epsilon)$ and go from there? Sorry for the amount of questions, I just don't see how to continue from your first hint.

Comment: @psyph You have to start with $P(X_n+Y_n \leq z)+P(|Y_n| >\epsilon) \geq P(X_n \leq z-\epsilon)$ and take $\lim \inf$.